# Hide {cli} messages in tests with {testthat}

Tags: r, r-package, testthat

I use [{cli}](https://cli.r-lib.org/) messages in one of my packages. I would like to hide these messages in my tests because they clutter the testthat results. Is there a way to do that?

I've seen that {cli} has a [TESTTHAT](https://cli.r-lib.org/reference/cli-config.html#testthat) environment variable but I don't know if it exists for this purpose, and I don't know how to use it. Note that I would prefer a solution that is simple to implement, such as a test global option. I don't want to manually edit all my tests or messages.

Reproducible example:

```r
library(testthat)
library(cli)

test_that("addition works", {
  cli_alert_info("This message should not appear")
  expect_equal(1+1, 2)
})

#> i This message should not appear
#> Test passed
```

---

**Edit:** I could create a custom `test_that()` that would wrap `suppressMessages()` like the following:

```r
my_test_that <- function(desc, code) {
  test_that(desc, {
    suppressMessages({
      code
    })
  })
}

my_test_that("addition works", {
  cli_alert_danger("This message should not appear")
  expect_equal(1+1, 2)
})

#> Test passed
```

and then store it in `tests/testthat/setup.R`. The problem is that if a test fails, it indicates the line in `my_test_that()` and not the line where the error actually appears (so basically all errors and warnings will refer to the same line):

```r
my_test_that("addition works", {
  cli_alert_danger("This message should not appear")
  expect_equal(1+4, 2)
})

-- Failure (.active-rstudio-document:6:5): addition works ----------------------
1 + 4 (`actual`) not equal to 2 (`expected`).
```

Here, the error refers to the line with `suppressMessages()`. This makes it much harder to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution was given in [this Github issue](https://github.com/r-lib/cli/issues/434). Using `withr::with_options()` or `withr::local_options()` with `option cli.default_handler = function(...) { }` seems to work.

```r
library(testthat)
library(cli)

my_test_that <- function(desc, code) {
  withr::with_options(
    list(
      cli.default_handler = function(...) { },
      usethis.quiet = TRUE
    ),
    test_that(desc, {
      code
    })
  )
}

my_test_that("addition works", {
  cli_alert_danger("This message should not appear")
  expect_equal(1+2, 2)
})

-- Failure (.active-rstudio-document:15:3): addition works ---------------------
1 + 2 not equal to 2.
1/1 mismatches
[1] 3 - 2 == 1
```

Note that this will remove all `cli` messages so it is not possible to use `expect_message()` in `my_test_that()`.